# Options in renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the options for my renderDataTable.

My code in the file Server.R looks like this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 output$distance<-renderDataTable({
A<-input$title
binding<-cbind(Row1=names(DF1),Distanz =DF1[,A,drop=FALSE])
as.data.frame(binding[order(binding[2]),])
  })
```

I tried to just add options after a comma:

```
    ...as.data.frame(binding[order(binding[2]),])
  ,options = Null})
```

I get the error "unexpected token ','"

When i try it without the "," it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options need to go after the curly bracket:

```
...as.data.frame(binding[order(binding[2]),])
  },options = Null)
```